# Why is pandas only writing one data point to my csv from my variables?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to write 9 data points to a csv. My output looks like this:

```
1991579
['NC_021181.2']
4843789
['NZ_CP010820.1']
4848754
['NZ_CP009756.1']
5227419
['NC_007530.2']
3018755
['NC_013205.1']
5190487
['NZ_LR134475.1']
5762608
['NZ_CP009909.1']
5598454
['NZ_CP050508.1']
4215606
['NC_000964.3']
```

I want each ID to accompany each number in my dataframe. My code at the moment only writes one row. Am I missing something?

```
work_dir = "/Users/
for path in glob.glob(os.path.join(work_dir, "*.gbff")):
    with io.open(path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        first_line = file.readline()
        matches = int(re.search(r"(\d+)", first_line[33:]).group(0))
        print(matches)
    name = os.path.basename(path).replace(".gbff", "")
    names_list = []
    names_list.append(name)
    print(names_list)

#output as file
df = pd.DataFrame({'Accession_ID':names_list, 'Genome_size': matches})
print(df)
df.to_csv(r'/Users/, index=False)
```

Thank you!!

Comment: You are clearing out `names_list` on every loop.  You should initialize that once, before the loop starts.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your input data? This would make it easier to test your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are clearing out `names_list` on every loop.  You should initialize that once, before the loop starts.